# What should be the name for values folder for developer english in android

Tags: android

What i want is the name of value folder which consists of String.xml , In that XML i have written key-key pairing i.e   "NAME"
 "EMPLOYEE_ID". If i use any language key word say en,fi, that will not a good practice. So what should be the name of value folder for above string.xml. 
Thank you.

Comment: @Ravi - i.e <string name="name">"name"</string> Usually we write here name-key and value-sog , we call this string by id we will get its value. So as to see my ids i have pair like key - key . When i call this string by id i will get what id's i have used in my app.

Comment: If i give name like values-sv OR values-fi , It will not a good practice for above scenario. All i need , what should be folder name for above scenario.

Comment: It should go in the `values` folder only preferably in a different xml file say, string_keys.xml (the name can be anything, there are no rules on that). But, I'm still not convinced why are you localizing the string keys themselves. How do you plan on using them?

Comment: @ Ravi The plan is i have opetion in my app name show strind id's for texts , so i map key-key pairing.

Comment: @Ravi- But then how one call that string_keys.xml file . generally we use locale when we switch to languages.

Answer (score 0):

Bydefault for english language it will pickup from values folder and for supporting languages you can refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Comment: @Fahim- Yes it will take by default english language , but that xml consists of id-key value-name , In my scenario xml consists id-key value-key.

Answer (score 0):

You should save this xml in the `values` folder only. Android is not bothered about what the *keys* are being mapped to; it just makes sure it returns the right value respecting the overrides if any for a particular device's `Locale` settings.

So, whether the *key* maps to a *value* or to some value's *key* itself, has no bearing on the `values` folder it should go in; but it should preferably be stored in a different xml file, say, *string_keys.xml* or something.

*values/strings.xml*

```
<string name="employee_name">Name</string>
```

*values/strings_keys.xml*

```
<string name="employee_name_key">employee_name</string>
```

Comment: But then how one call that string_keys.xml file . generally we use locale when we switch to languages.

Comment: All the xml files under `values` (no matter what their names are) will be parsed by the Android resource compiler and all the string resources found in any of those xml files will be made available through `R.string` ids. So, the above key would be available as `R.string.employee_name_key` when you compile  your application. You can verify this in the generated `R.java` file as well.